# How to center li in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Normally, I would just do `position: relative` and do `left: 500px`. But, the best part about Bootstrap is that it's responsive. I don't want to get rid of the responsive feature of Bootstrap. How do I center an li in Bootstrap inside of my nav?

**Please view the snippet in Full Page mode. My goal is to move the two "Links" to the middle of the div. They are both li's. How do I accomplish this?**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- This file has been downloaded from Bootsnipp.com. Enjoy! -->
    <title>Fancy navbar login / sign in form - Bootsnipp.com</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
    background:url('http://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2012/10/21/20181/cad2441dd3252cf53f12154412286ba0.jpg');
    padding:50px;
}

#login-dp{
    min-width: 250px;
    padding: 14px 14px 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.8);
}
#login-dp .help-block{
    font-size:12px    
}
#login-dp .bottom{
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    border-top:1px solid #ddd;
    clear:both;
    padding:14px;
}
#login-dp .social-buttons{
    margin:12px 0    
}
#login-dp .social-buttons a{
    width: 49%;
}
#login-dp .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.btn-fb{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#3b5998;
}
.btn-fb:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#496ebc 
}
.btn-tw{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#55acee;
}
.btn-tw:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#59b5fa;
}
@media(max-width:768px){
    #login-dp{
        background-color: inherit;
        color: #fff;
    }
    #login-dp .bottom{
        background-color: inherit;
        border-top:0 none;
    }
}

    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Login dropdown</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
 
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><p class="navbar-text">Already have an account?</p></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Login</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
   <ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
        Login via
        <div class="social-buttons">
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>
        </div>
                                or
         <form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="login" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email address" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password" required>
                                             <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="">Forget the password ?</a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox"> keep me logged-in
            </label>
          </div>
         </form>
       </div>
       <div class="bottom text-center">
        New here ? <a href="#"><b>Join Us</b></a>
       </div>
      </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>


</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just you can do it in this way--
Add a class `.navbar-centre` to the ul which contains the links to be centered.
Then add the css like the snippet.

```css
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav.navbar-center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         
  </head>

  <body>
    
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Login dropdown</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
 
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><p class="navbar-text">Already have an account?</p></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Login</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                Login via
                <div class="social-buttons">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>
                </div>
                                or
                 <form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="login" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">
                    <div class="form-group">
                       <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
                       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email address" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                       <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
                       <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password" required>
                                             <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="">Forget the password ?</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                       <label>
                       <input type="checkbox"> keep me logged-in
                       </label>
                    </div>
                 </form>
              </div>
              <div class="bottom text-center">
                New here ? <a href="#"><b>Join Us</b></a>
              </div>
           </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
  </body>

</html>
```